# How to handle unknown number of items from a form in php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, dynamic

Working on making an inventory page for work. I have written a page that will loop through my data base and display all of the items in there.

```
include 'auth.php'; //to change login, please authenticate 
$sql="SELECT * FROM `inventory` ORDER BY `id` asc;";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo    $rows["name"];
<input type="text" name="<? echo $rows["id"];  ?>" id="<? echo $rows["id"] ?>" placeholder="Who will go in here?" />
}
```

The above code is doing what I want. I would like to put this in a form and have a submit button. Let's say the form is

```
<form method="POST" action="page.php">
```

Now I want to be able to write a page.php so that it can handle all of the data regardless of the number of items. In the past I have done the following

```
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$phone=$_POST['phonenum'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$age = $_POST['b18'];
```

But that won't work as I will have an unknown amount of post. Please write any code you like. I prefer document pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$_POST is just an ordinary hash array, so you can loop over it

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  print "{$key}: {$value}<br />";
}
```

---

edit
well you need to do some special adjustments, if your values are array values (POST key with [] at the end of the name)

---

edit
it's of no use if you try

```
foreach ($_POST as $varname => $value) {
  ${$varname} = $value;
}
```

because you don't know the name of the variables;

Comment: Can you give me an example on my first code segment on how to turn them into array values.

Comment: I guess my question is, What does "as $key => $value" do. What is $key and what is $value.

Comment: @user1048138 If you have an array `$a = array(); $a['key1'] = 'val1'; $['key2'] = 'val2';` then the loop with the `foreach` and `$key=>$value` will make in the first run `$key = 'key1'` and `$value = 'val1'` in the second run `$key = 'key2'` and `$value = 'val2'`

Comment: You have no idea how happy you have made me. Ive been working on this for the longest times.

Answer (score 0):

I will start from your code

```
include 'auth.php'; //to change login, please authenticate 
 $sql="SELECT * FROM `inventory` ORDER BY `id` asc;";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo    $rows["name"];
<input type="text" name="id[]" id="<? echo $rows["id"] ?>" value = "<? echo $rows["id"] ?>"      placeholder="Who will go in here?" />
}
```

Now in your page.php

```
<?php 
foreach($_POST['id'] as $id):
  echo $id; 
endforeach;
?>
```

This will print out all the values of the input named id[] 
What i did for you is naming the input with array at the end and then print that array 
I hope that's what you want

Comment: How would that work. $_POST['id'] will return anything with name 'id' from the first page (the first code). the 2nd page will just take the first one since it is not directly connected to the DB.

Comment: no the input now acting like an array 
so I parsed it using the foreach